# How can i use multiple cells in range method in vba

Tags: vba

I am trying to set up two range in cells method. I am trying to select E and G so i was using.

```
  ActiveSheet.Range ("D" & ActiveCell.Row & ":G" & ActiveCell.Row)
```

Kept on getting an error. Is there any other way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

You must use **Set**:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("D" & ActiveCell.Row & ":G" & ActiveCell.Row)
    MsgBox rng.Address
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: what if i want to do something like this sumx = WorksheetFunction.sum(Sheet1.Range(Cells(5, i), Cells(8, ii)))... Some of two cell.. is it going to work out or any ideas

Comment: @user3795861  It should work either way.

Comment: @ Gary's Studentits not working its adding both of my sum togther

Comment: Students Can you give any ideas on this one http://superuser.com/questions/940201/how-can-i-add-numbers-using-sum-function-in-vba-between-ranges?noredirect=1#comment1279447_940201